# c# One Class for all winforms textboxes and comboboxes events without direct calling

Tags: c#, winforms, events, overriding

i want to change background color and fontsize when textbox or combobox got focus . I have 23 forms and lot of controls. I want example of one public class which automatically handle gotfocus event and change properties.
I am Very Beginner Your Expert Opinion is valued Thanks a lot in advance

```
namespace LiabraryClasses.Library
```

{

```
// General Events Handler Class
class GEVENTS 
{

    public override void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Increase font size  and background color 


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a group of TextBoxes of which you don't want normal behaviour but some special behaviour when they get focus, the neat object oriented way to do this would be to create a special TextBox class that changes Font and BackColor when focussed.

```
public class MySpecialTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Font FontIfFocussed {get; set;}            // TODO: assign default values
    public Font FontIfNotFocussed {get; set;}
    public Color BackColorIfFocussed {get; set;}
    public color BackColorIfNotFocussed {get; set;}

    protected override OnGotFocus(Eventargs e)
    {
        // TODO: set font size and background color of this TextBox
    }

    protected override OnLostFocus(Eventargs e)
    {
        // TODO: set font size and background color of this TextBox
    }
}
```

This way, you can select in visual studio designer what kind of TextBox you want: a normal one, or one that changes color and fond.

But if you really want to use the original TextBox class and change it:

```
class MyWindow
{
    private myTextBox;
    private Font fontIfFocussed = ..
    private Font FontIfNotFocussed = ...
    private Color BackColorIfFocussed = ...
    private color BackColorIfNotFocussed = ...

    public MyWindow()
    {
        this.myTextBox = new TextBox();
        this.fontIfFocussed = new Font(this.myTextBox.Font.FontFamily, 16);
        this.backColorIfFocussed = Color.AliceBlue;
        ...

        this.myTextBox.GotFocus += this.OnGotFocus();
    }

    public void OnGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender as Control control != null)
        {
             control.Font = this.fontIfFocussed;
             control.BackColor = this.backColorIfFocussed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks sir let me try this